# Randomly initialized embedding matrix

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, word-embeddings

The Tensorflow LSTM example uses a word embedding layer (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html).  However, it mentions that 'the embedding matrix will be initialized randomly and the model will learn to differentiate the meaning of words just by looking at the data'.  I think this means that pretrained embeddings (e.g. using Word2Vec) are not used.  I have two questions with regards to this.

1. Are there any variables/weights (e.g. adjusted during back prop) associates with the word_embedding layer in this RNN?  Or is it purely a static lookup table to randomly assigned variables?
2. Do random word embeddings have any advantages over just adding a regular hidden layer with the same dimensions as the randomly initialized word embedding layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this means that pretrained embeddings (e.g. using Word2Vec) are not used.

Correct

> Are there any variables/weights (e.g. adjusted during back prop) associated with the word_embedding layer in this RNN? Or is it purely a static lookup table to randomly assigned variables?

First option: there are any variables/weights (e.g. adjusted during back prop) associated with the word_embedding layer in this RNN.

> Do random word embeddings have any advantages over just adding a regular hidden layer with the same dimensions as the randomly initialized word embedding layer?

It is the equivalent: adding a random word embedding layer means adding a regular hidden layer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  tf.trainable_variables() does indeed show that the embeddings variable is trainable.  When you say it's equivalent, does that mean behind the scenes tf.nn.embedding_lookup is creating activation(Wx+B) tensors on each dimension of the vector automatically?